# Name of a movie where Earth surrenders

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for the name of a made for TV movie that has an alien weapon on either the Moon or Mars.

They fire the weapon which goes through the Earth, in one side out the other. A girl in Maine figures it is an automatic weapon and sends a message surrendering the earth.

All the governments get mad at her for surrendering the Earth but she points out it will take the message 200 light-years to get the message to the aliens home planet. In the hundreds of years it will take to get the message there and for the aliens to get back, the Earth has time to arm itself for the upcoming invasion.

Anyone know the name of this movie?

Comment: ..."Stop shooting, we surrender!"  200 years later: "Hey, they surrendered, I guess we can... stop... firing... now...".

Comment: A.E Titan Intelligence

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I think that the point was that they told the weapon that they surrendered. Because the aliens know about the length of time for communication, they presumably allowed for autonomy of the automated weapon to stop firing. Although, after this, they might not any more...

Comment: Is this a live action movie or animated?